# How to align with respect to a symbol inside the argument of a command?

Tags: alignat, overset

I would like to align several lines with respect to a symbol, say an equality sign, above which something else is written (using `\overset`), while taking that, what is written above the symbol, into account for spacing, like this:
[image]

However, I cannot put the "&" into the argument of `\overset`, as this seems to be syntactically forbidden. When placing it next to `\overset`, the lines are, of course, not aligned with respect to the equality sign:
[image]

I tried using `\mathclap`, which provides the alignment I want, but then the spacing gets too tight:
[image]
Here is my minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,fleqn]{article}

\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, graphics, setspace}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

Placing "\&" next to overset:
\begin{alignat*}{1}
\textrm{some expression} & \overset{(23.1)}{=}\textrm{other expression}\\
 & \overset{(1.3)}{=}\textrm{other expression}\\
 & \overset{(2.4,3.5)}{=}\textrm{other expression}
\end{alignat*}

Using mathclap:
\begin{alignat*}{1}
\textrm{some expression} & \overset{\mathclap{(23.1)}}{=}\textrm{other expression}\\
 & \overset{\mathclap{(1.3)}}{=}\textrm{other expression}\\
 & \overset{\mathclap{(2.4,3.5)}}{=}\textrm{other expression}
\end{alignat*}

How I want it to look like:
\begin{alignat*}{1}
\textrm{some expression} & \quad\overset{\mathclap{(23.1)}}{=}\quad\textrm{other expression}\\
 & \quad\overset{\mathclap{(1.3)}}{=}\quad\textrm{other expression}\\
 & \quad\overset{\mathclap{(2.4,3.5)}}{=}\quad\textrm{other expression}
\end{alignat*}
Of course, adding spaces manually as done here is not a satisfactory solution to the problem.

\end{document}
```

Comment: is the `alignat` a necessary environment for your purposes? if not, perhaps an arrangement using an `array` environment may help? e.g `\[
\begin{array}{r@{}c@{}l}
\textrm{some expression} & \overset{{(23.1)}}{=}&\textrm{other expression}\\
 & \overset{{(1.3)}}{=}&\textrm{other expression}\\
 & \overset{{(2.4,3.5)}}{=}&\textrm{other expression}
\end{array}
\]`

Comment: *(looks like I was thinking along the same lines as Herbert)*

Comment: I chose the alignat environment because it is page-breakable and allows numbering single lines. If this is possible with array, then array is fine for me as well.

Answer (score 7):

```
\[
    \begin{array}{r@{}c@{}l}
    \textrm{some expression} & \overset{(23.1)}{=}  &\textrm{other expression}\\
                             & \overset{(1.3)}{=} & \textrm{other expression}\\
                             & \overset{(2.4,3.5)}{=} &\textrm{other expression}
    \end{array}
\]
```

[image]

or for less space:

```
\begin{array}{r@{\kern-2pt}c@{\kern-2pt}l}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this works nicely. Is there a way to make this array environment page-breakable?

Comment: Yes, but only in Text mode with a longtable. You have to use the $...$  Notation for math

Answer (score 3):

This uses a `\tabularCenterstack` from the `tabstackengine` package.  Intercolumn width is controlled by `\setstacktabulargap{0pt}`.  Interrow baselineskip is controlled by `\setstackgap{L}{1.4\baselineskip}`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,fleqn]{article}

\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, graphics, setspace}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\stackMath
\def\poverset{\protect\overset}
\setstackgap{L}{1.4\baselineskip}
\setstacktabulargap{0pt}
\begin{document}

Using \verb|\tabularCenterstack|:
\[
\tabularCenterstack{rcl}{
\textrm{some expression} & \poverset{(23.1)}{=}&\textrm{other expression}\\
 & \poverset{(1.3)}{=}&\textrm{other expression}\\
 & \poverset{(2.4,3.5)}{=}&\textrm{other expression}
}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this works nicely. Is there a way to make this tabularCenterstack environment page-breakable?